# Prestashop Api Url Always Redirects To Login Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

I have private shop made with prestashop, i have activated the webservice and generated an api key, i have checked also .htaccess file and it is normal too. but each time i navigate to api url i get redirected to the login page.

Comment: Please post your htaccess rules file in your question along with by hitting which URL(examples will work) what is the error or unexpected behavior you are getting, thank you.

Comment: We need exact examples. May be you need to pass user credentials?